# Passing A Delegate In prepareForSegue Method

Tags: core-data, delegates

I am having a problem passing an object from a TableView to a ViewController in an IOS app. I am using storyboard and have elected ARC and passing the delegate in my "prepareForSegue" method.

Here is my code in my TableView which segues via a push to another ViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NextViewController *vc = (NextViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    vc.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditCategory"])
    {

    NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

    //  I get a red warning which states "Cast of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'Entity' is disallowed with ARC" on this line:
    [vc setEntity:(Entity *)selectedIndex];
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for how I can pass my object from the TableView to the ViewController? I am new to programming and have tried various expressions but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting has to do with types.

The class `NextViewController` apparently has a method called `-setEntity:` that takes an object of type `Entity *`. The error is because you're trying to give `-setEntity:` an argument of the wrong type. You're trying to give it an `NSInteger` (which is a number like 0, 5, -999), but it wants an `Entity`.

You're on the right track for passing data from the table view to the `NextViewController`. You just need to do one of the following:

- pass an `Entity` to `-setEntity:` (does the `Entity` class perhaps
  have a constructor that takes an `NSInteger`?)
- add a method to `NextViewController` that takes an `NSInteger`, and call that instead of `-setEntity:`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I've been trying to implement the protocol/delegate methods but my managedObject is coming up "null".  I think I'm having trouble deciding which view controller is actually passing the managedObject.  The results of a picker on the ViewController are merely displayed on the TableViewController.  Do I only need to pass the managedObject one way from the ViewController to the TableViewController?  Or do I need to pass the managedObject in both directions?